# Bitnami - exec: "zookeeper-shell.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kcat

I have installed kafka on docker with following yml

```
version: "3"
services:
 zookeeper:
image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
ports:
  - '2181:2181'
environment:
  - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
 kafka:
image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'

ports:
  - '9092:9092'
  - '9093:9093'
environment:
  - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
  - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
  - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://myserver.com:9093
  - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
  - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
```

i installed kafkacat on machine (linux on wsl2),dockerapp_zookeeper_1 is container for zookeper, and trying to run

```
docker exec -t dockerapp_zookeeper_1 \
 zookeeper-shell.sh \
   localhost:2181 \
   ls /brokers/ids
```

i am getting error

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "zookeeper-shell.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

file is there i checked , why i am getting this error, do i need to install kafkacat on docker itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with kcat.

You'll need to provide the absolute path to the Zookeeper shell script, which I believe is under /opt in that container, or try without `.sh`

If you actually wanted to use kcat, that has nothing to do with Zookeeper, and, no, doesn't need its own container. You'd run it with `kcat`, not `docker exec`